# Eclipse E4 - Menu contribution and PersistedState

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

I have got ditched in a problem with Menu Contribution and PersistedState. I had no problem before removing the -clearPersistedState flag from the VM args.

Now, the app has a weird behaviour, the menu contribution starts to pile up a menu entry every time the code is executed.

Here it's the guilty snippet enclosed in a Processor:

```
MDirectMenuItem menuItem = MMenuFactory.INSTANCE.createDirectMenuItem();
    menuItem.setLabel("Another Exit");
    menuItem.setContributionURI("bundleclass://"
            + "com.telespazio.optsat.wizard/"
            + ExitHandlerWithCheck.class.getName());
    if (!menu.getChildren().contains(menuItem))
        menu.getChildren().add(menuItem);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu items you add to the application model will be persisted, so you need to check if they already exist in the menu. The `contains` check you currently have does not do this.

You need to check for a match of the label (or the contribution URI, or the id), something like:

```
List<MMenuElement> children = menu.getChildren();

boolean gotExisting = false;

for (MMenuElement child : children)
 {
   if ("Another Exit".equals(child.getLabel())
    {
      gotExisting = true;
      break;
    }
 }

if (!gotExisting)
 {
   ... add to menu
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, just for my own curiosity, does the approach of not clearing the Persistent State create other weird behaviours? What I meant to say is what should I expect after the flag removal?

Comment: There were problems with fragments but these may have been resolved by now.

Comment: do you mean there were some bugs? Basically I think that the -clearPersistedState flag has been automatically added into my configuration by Eclipse itself, it's because I was wondering that...

Comment: When you are testing a new app you need -clearPersistedState so that the design changes you make to the Application.e4xmi are picked up

Comment: So are you suggesting to me to set back that flag? Otherwise if I amend the Application.e4xmi some changes won't take effect?