# Dynamic Menu contribution and PersistedState

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

How do I get the `menu` instance in the answer given in the following question?

[Existing Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550002/eclipse-e4-menu-contribution-and-persistedstate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `EModelService` to find the menu by its id.

```java
@Inject
EModelService modelService;

List<MMenu> list = modelService.findElements(app, "menu id", MMenu.class, 
                          Collections.emptyList(), EModelService.IN_MAIN_MENU);
```

You must use the `findElements` call with the `EModelService.IN_MAIN_MENU` flag to search the menus.

Comment: Unfortunately the `modelService.find("menu id", application);` returns null in my `@AboutToShow` method. Do you know why?

Comment: In @AboutToShow you can get the menu elements list as a parameter - added this to answer

Comment: Yes, but this list is always empty, as also mentioned [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/Dependency_Injection#.40AboutToShow.2C_.40AboutToHide_.28org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.29)

Comment: Sorry, researching this a bit more the normal find does not work for menus, you have to use findElements with a flag. Updated the answer